# ¿Como conectarme a una Base de datos SQL Server desde Hosting Neubox?

Tags: php, sql-server, base-de-datos, hosting, odbc

Como puedo conectarme a mi base de datos SQL server desde mi servidor de hosting que en este caso es Neubox(Cpanel). Lo estoy realizando mediante PHP y PDO, pero me manda el siguiente error:

```
SQLSTATE[IMSSP]: This extension requires the Microsoft ODBC Driver for SQL Server to communicate with SQL Server.
```

En mi hosting, habilité las siguientes extenciones de PHP: pdo, pdo_sqlsrv, odbc y pdo_odbc

Se que el error manda que requiero ODBC driver pero en este caso en el hosting ya seleccioné la extensión de odbc.

Alguien tiene alguna solución u otro método?

El código que utilicé para la conexión es este:

```
<?php

try {

    $host='***';
    $dbname='***';
    $username = '***';
    $pasword = '****';
    $puerto = '1400';

    $conn = new PDO("sqlsrv:Server = $host, $puerto; Database = $dbname",$username,$pasword);
    echo 'Se conectó al sistema correctamente';

    
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo "Error al establecer la conexión  " .$e->getMessage();
}

?>
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: y el codigo que usas para conectarte??? pareciera que estas usando ODBC y por eso detecta que necesitas el driver...

Comment: Información relacionada: https://fredyfx.wordpress.com/2013/03/18/drupal-en-iis-con-sql-server/

Comment: Listo, actualicé el comentario con el código de conexión